# PHP strip unknown file extension

Tags: php, string, file-extension

I understand that using PHP's `basename()` function you can strip a known file extension from a path like so,

```
basename('path/to/file.php','.php')
```

but what if you didn't know what extension the file had or the length of that extension? How would I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) was already mentioned here, but I'd like to add that **from PHP 5.2** it also has a simple way to access the filename WITHOUT the extension.

```
$filename = pathinfo('path/to/file.php', PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

The value of `$filename` will be `file`.

Comment: Great, I forgot about it. It should be the accepted answer - no hacks, regexes, string manipulation and only one line.

Comment: @galymzhan No worries about the accepted answer, I just added it for future reference. Your solution is still good for people stuck with PHP < 5.2.

Comment: Thanks I'm accepting your answer! -It's one line of code and a little simpler.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the extension using [pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo) and cut it off.

```
// $filepath = '/path/to/some/file.txt';
$ext = pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$basename = basename($filepath, ".$ext");
```

Note the `.` before `$ext`

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = preg_replace('@\.([^\.]+)$@', '', $filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$path = 'path/to/file.php';

$pathParts = pathinfo( $path );

$pathWihoutExt = $pathParts['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $pathParts['filename'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
$filepath = 'path/to/file.extension';
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filepath, '.'), 1));
```